# Openshift- External Elasticsearch configuration

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-3

I have a Openshift Cluster setup in which I have aggregated Openshift logging.
Elasticsearch , fluentd and Kibana.

I have setup external elastic search on different server. I want to forward my Openshift cluster logs to my newly setup Elasticsearch.

Please help me in resolving this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is explained in https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/aggregate_logging.html#sending-logs-to-an-external-elasticsearch-instance

From your question it's not clear what problem you are facing.